# JWT token issue on Azure Management API

Tags: azure

I've been trying to use the Azure Service Management API in order to list the Hosted Services with no success.

In the first place, I was able to set up the authentication using PowerShell as the Microsoft documentation states here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790557.aspx

My first step was to request an access token using OAuth2 making a POST request to this URL:

```
https://login.windows.net/<MY_TENANT_ID>/oauth2/token
```

and passing these parameters:

```
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: <THE_CLIENT_ID_OF_THE_APP_REGISTERED_THROUGH_POWERSHELL>
client_secret: <THE_PASSWORD_OF_APP_REGISTERED_THROUGH_POWERSHELL>
resource: https://management.core.windows.net
```

so, I receive a valid response and an access_token included in the response. So far so good.

Then, I want to make a simple call to the Management API; I would like to list my Hosted Services (Cloud Services), so I make a GET request to this URL:

```
https://management.core.windows.net/<MY_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/services/hostedservices
```

Including the following headers:

```
Authorization: Bearer <THE_ACCESS_TOKEN_RECEIVED_IN_THE_PREVIOUS_STEP>
x-ms-version: 2014-10-01 (I've also tested with different versions)
```

but, what I get is a 401 Unauthorized error, with the following message:

```
The JWT token does not contain expected audience uri 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
```

I also tried with a Native Application registered directly in the Azure Portal (with Permissions set to use the Service Management API) and requesting a token using the `grant_type = authorization_code`. I get the access_token correctly and a refresh_token, but when I try to make a request to the above URL, I get the same error message.

On a side note, I am able to use the Azure Insights API successfully; the issue above is with the Azure Service Management API.

Anyone knows what I am missing?

Comment: Same issue here, can't seem to figure out why I keep obtaining Unauthorized.

Comment: I am able to access the following end points through AAD based tokens:
i. https://graph.windows.net/
ii. https://management.azure.com/ But https://management.core.windows.net/ could be accessed only through management certificate, looks like a known limitation even with the latest API versions.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today. Complete the resource url with **'/'** https://management.core.windows.net

See the mismatch between the url in your resource and the one in the error message 'https://management.core.windows.net**/**'

Comment: I had seen at that time someone mentioning about the trailing slash but that didn't work either.

Comment: I agree @RolandPish. Looks lie this API: https://management.core.windows.net/  got some problem with authentication tokens

Comment: @ArunkumarKumaresan Any updates on this issue? I'm facing it today still.